# React Redux: How to get a random object from state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, lodash

I'm new to React Redux. I'm trying to get a random object from state (array of objects). I fetch data through action creator, and shuffle the objects using lodash. I also use slice to limit the amount of objects. I'm going to use those same objects on another component too.

The following is my action:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export const fetchItems = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos") // fetch 5000 items
  const data = await response.json();

  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ITEMS', payload: _.shuffle(data.slice(0, 8)) })
}
```

To get a random object from state, I used Math.random to generate a random number and used it to access the array of objets. However the following code gives me an error: **this.props.news[Math.floor(...)] is undefined**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchItems } from '../actions';

class Title extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchItems();
  }

  renderList() {
     return (
       <h2>{this.props.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.data.length)].title}</h2>
     )
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="jumbotron">
        {this.renderList()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { data: state.data }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchItems: fetchItems })(Title);
```

How do I get a random object on Title component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error: this.props.news[Math.floor(...)] is undefined` is simply saying that at *some* "random" index that there is no defined value from which to access a `title` property of.

My guess here is that `props.data` is initially empty. You can use Optional Chaining to guard against undefined accesses, `this.props.data[randomIndex]?.title`.

```
renderList() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.data.length);
  return (
    <h2>{this.props.data[randomIndex]?.title}</h2>
  )
}
```

If you are unable to use Optional Chaining then apply a guard clause.

```
renderList() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.data.length);
  return (
    <h2>{this.props.data[randomIndex] && this.props.data[randomIndex].title}</h2>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked. I tried ``if(!this.props.news) return null;`` in case the data is not ready, but it seems that was not the right way to solve the empty state problem...

Comment: @kayak Right, yeah, `[]` is a truthy defined object.